# Simple guessing game that allows user to play again after correctly guessing the random number?

Tags: c, function, random

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<time.h>

int random_num;
void guessGame(int guessed_num){

    char answer;
if (guessed_num == random_num){
    printf("Correct! That's the number.\n");
    printf("Would you like to play again (y or n)?\n");
    scanf("%c", &answer);
    if (answer=='y')
        scanf("%d", &guessed_num);
        guessGame(guessed_num);
    if (answer=='n')
        return 0;


}
else
    if (guessed_num < random_num)
        printf("Too low. Guess again.\n");
    else
        printf("Too high. Guess again.\n");
}

int main(){

int guessed_num = 0;
srand(time(NULL));
random_num = rand() % 50 + 1;

printf("I have a number between 1-50.\n");
printf("Can you guess what it is?\n");
printf("Enter your initial guess.\n");

while(1){

    scanf("%d", &guessed_num);
    guessGame(guessed_num);
}

return 0;
}
```

So after the user finds the correct random number, I want them to be able to play the game again(if they want). How do I go about having the code run all over again? I tried to do it in my guessGame function but I know it's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since my english is not good, i will give you the code ( modifed from yours).

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    #include<math.h>
    #include<time.h>

    int random_num;

    int guessGame(int guessed_num) {


        if (guessed_num == random_num) {
           printf("Correct! That's the number.\n");
           return 1;
        } else if (guessed_num < random_num) {
              printf("Too low. Guess again.\n");
              return 0;
           } else {
              printf("Too high. Guess again.\n");
             return 0;
        }
    }

    int main() {
    char loop;
    while (1) {
    int guessed_num = 0;
    srand(time(NULL));
    random_num = rand() % 50 + 1;
    printf("I have a number between 1-50.\n");
    printf("Can you guess what it is?\n");
    printf("Enter your initial guess.\n");
    while (1) {
        scanf("%d", &guessed_num);
        int returnValue = guessGame(guessed_num);
        if (returnValue == 1) {
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("You wanna do it again? ");
    getchar();
    scanf("%c", &loop);
    if (loop == 'n') {
        break;
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I see is to have guessGame return a bool. True if they get it right, false if they get it wrong. Then in your main, have another bool variable, let's say guessedRight, set it to guessGame's return value, and use that as the while loop condition.

Maybe even easier is to move the line where you get the guess from the user into the guessGame function (and then it takes no arguments). Then your attempt to call geussGame again should work.

So option 1: Edit the beginning of guessGame

```
void guessGame(){
    int guessed_num = 0;
    scanf("%d", &guessed_num);
```

And just completely remove the

```
if (answer = 'n')
  return 0;
```

It serves no purpose and your function was a void return type anyways. Then just call guessGame in main. You also don't need a while loop with this approach.

Option 2: change the return type of guessGame

```
bool guessGame(){
     int guessed_num = 0;
     scanf("%d", &guessed_num);
```

scan, get the answer, then

```
if (answer = 'y')
    return true;

return false
```

Then in main, I think you can actually just do

```
while(guessGame()) {}
```

Comment: hey thanks for the help. I actually edited my question. I meant to say:"Simple guessing game that allows user to play again after correctly guessing the random number?"

Comment: @abhishek_naik hey there